# What is the difference between UX testing and usability testing?

Tags: usability-testing, definition

What is the difference between UX testing and usability testing?

For example Wikipedia simply [redirects "UX testing" to "Usability testing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=UX_testing&redirect=no) (as of 2021-10-18)

While for example [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41352/usability-testing-vs-ux-testing-what-is-the-difference) there are claims that there are differences, but I am not too impressed by answer quality. Similarly say https://fuzzymath.com/blog/difference-between-usability-and-user-experience/

This page has https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/usability-testing/info but no mention of UX testing there - and no equivalent UX testing tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usability testing is an observational methodology to test out products with users.
UX Testing I believe encompasses all methods to test and measure the UX like:
Usability studies,
Card sorting,
Heuristics etc.